# One of (the) important facts

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I would like to say something like

"One of (the)important facts in mathematics is ABC theorem."

I am wondering if I need "the" or not. The reason I am confusing is that the importance of facts is personal and could be non-definitive.

So I guess I don't need "the". Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: One of **the** important theorems in mathematics is ABC.

Comment: One of several of any noun (*facts* in your example) will always be countable (1) so an article is needed. *important* modifies *facts* only to say that "ABC theorem" is important. There is no general importance stated.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, "One of the most important theorems..."

> ...if you want to emphasize this theorem, or...

"One important theorem..." or "An important theorem..."

> ...if you do not need to emphasize this theorem.